# XPages and data reflection (integration with PrimeFaces)

Tags: xpages

I need to have complicated grid for reflecting data with following features: sorting, filtering, pagination, and categorization (like in Notes Views). Additional features like resizing and reorderign of columns, add\remove columns by user, etc - are also welcome! )

Currently I’m considering Server-Side logic, like PrimeFaces (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableHome.jsf).

Need support in how to integrate PrimeFaces into XPages? Or are there any suggestions, what library to use to reflect data in tables?

*P.S. Currently I’m using DoJo EnchancedGrid. But it doesn’t support categories, this is first concern. And second - it is Client-Side logic, what is also not the best for my project.*

Comment: In case there is no Server-Side alternatives - I'm considering to replace DoJo with Ext JS, as I think it's the most powerful framework I met.

Comment: Ext JS is great.  Check out xomino.com, Mark Roden has written extensively on the use of Ext JS in xpages.

Comment: One word of caution about Ext JS.  Unlike dojo, Ext JS will do nothing on a mobile device.  It has no touch capability at all.  I believe the same company sells a separate product that support touch.

Comment: Dojo does support categories in grids using a variation called a TreeGrid. Brad Balassaitis has an epic series on Dojo grids in XPages, including some posts on TreeGrids, like this one: http://xcellerant.net/2013/05/28/categorized-dojo-grid/

Comment: P.S. When I search Google for "dojo grid categorized", the above link is the very first search result... just sayin'...

Comment: Tim, I know TreeGrid and also used it. But it almost features-less. It has simple sorting and nothing more. As I wrote in my topic - I need complicated grid with many features. TreeGrid is not what I looking for... And again - main quiestion: is it possible and how to integrate with PrimeFaces? (as main issue - to use ServerSide logic)

Comment: Andrew: what did you try so far? You could wrap it into a OSGi plugin as extension library and see if it compiles if you use it. The individual stumbling stones make better so questions

Comment: Stephan's right: PrimeFaces is a JSF component library, so you should be able to port it to Domino via the XPages Extensibility API... but a tutorial on how to do this is *way* outside of the scope of a stackoverflow question, and the documentation you need to get started has been on the Domino development wiki for years. So *try* it first, then come back when you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for answers! Actually it was two main questions: 1) any other suggestions for complicated grids (server-side), 2) and if no, how to integrate PrimeFaces. I did suspect that PrimeFaces should be linked to Xpages somehow like extLib. Thanks for confirming my assumption. ) Hoped somebody already solve such integration and can share the guideline... ) I'll try to do it. ...I will share my experience in case of success! )